# How to implement dynamic values for *case* in c#?

Tags: c#, command-line

I have console app which I am consuming .net core web api methods. Everything works fine I need to implement dynamic **case**

My method I am using **Create Project**

```
        public static async Task<string> Create(string name, string kubesprayCurrentVersion)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {name, kubesprayCurrentVersion});
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await Token.GetToken());

            var loginResponse = await client.PostAsync(LibvirtUrls.createProjectUrl, data);

            Console.WriteLine("Response Status Code: " + (int) loginResponse.StatusCode);
            string result = loginResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return result;
        }
```

I am using inside **switch/case**

```
        Console.WriteLine($"Welcome to Taikun CLI");            
        Console.WriteLine("Get all projects list : taikun project list");           
        Console.WriteLine("Create project : taikun project create");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("For quit press q");           
        string value;
        do
        { 
            value = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (value)
            {
                case "taikun project list":
                    await Project.GetProjects();
                    break;
                case "taikun project create":
                    Console.WriteLine("Please specify project name");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please specify project kubespray version");
                    string kube = Console.ReadLine();
                    await Project.Create(name,kube);
                    break;                   
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Please specify valid command");
                    break;
            }

        } while (value != "q");
```

In this case after typing command **taikun project create** it will ask enter project name and kube version and it works fine. I need implement something like just enter one line.

**taikun project create --projectName --kubeVersion**.
Is it possible to add dynamic values to **case**?

Comment: You need to use a command line parser instead of matching against the raw input string.

Comment: I recommend using a framework or at least a package to achieve this, as CLI argument parsing can be quite tricky. I've personally had great success with [tyrrrz/clifx](https://github.com/tyrrrz/clifx)

Comment: Also you can check this project https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [CliFx](https://github.com/tyrrrz/clifx) library as @MindSwap suggested solved my solution.

Example code:

```
    [Command("taikun user create")]
    public class CreateUser : ICommand
    {
        [CommandOption("username", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [CommandOption("password", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public async ValueTask ExecuteAsync(IConsole console)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Username, Password});
            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, 
           "application/json");

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await 
            Token.GetToken());

            var loginResponse = await 
            client.PostAsync(LibvirtUrls.createUserUrl, data);

            await console.Output.WriteLineAsync("Response Status Code: " + 
           (int) loginResponse.StatusCode);
            string result = loginResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            await console.Output.WriteLineAsync(result);
        }
    }
```

Main method:

```
    static async Task<int> Main()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        return await new CliApplicationBuilder()
            .AddCommandsFromThisAssembly()
            .Build()
            .RunAsync();
    }
```

example of usage:

**taikun user create --username [username] --password [password]**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# 7 or newer this can be achieved with pattern matching ([See this blog post.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)).

**Switch statements with patterns**

```cs
switch(shape)
{
    case Circle c:
        WriteLine($"circle with radius {c.Radius}");
        break;
    case Rectangle s when (s.Length == s.Height):
        WriteLine($"{s.Length} x {s.Height} square");
        break;
    case Rectangle r:
        WriteLine($"{r.Length} x {r.Height} rectangle");
        break;
    default:
        WriteLine("<unknown shape>");
        break;
    case null:
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(shape));
}
```

So in your case you could write

```cs
switch (value)
{
     case "taikun project list":
        await Project.GetProjects();
        break;
     case String s when s.StartsWith("taikun project create"):
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify project name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify project kubespray version");
        string kube = Console.ReadLine();
        await Project.Create(name,kube);
        break;                   
     default:
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify valid command");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 7.0, the language supports pattern matching, as [Athanasios wrote in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60414320/2249175). Technically this answers your question, but I'd doubt that this is really what you want (unless your example was made up solely for the purpose of demonstrating some use-case). I'd rather go and implement an interpreter for the commands. You don't have to use pattern matching, but simply check for the correct operation to be set

```cs
TaikunCliCommand command;
do
{ 
    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    command = taikunCommandInterpreter.InterpretCommand(userInput);    

    switch (command.CommandType)
    {
        case CommandType.ListProjects:
            await Project.GetProjects();
            break;
        case CommandType.CreateProject:
            await CreateProject(command);       
        case CommandType.Invalid:
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify valid command");
            break;
    }
} while (command.CommandType != CommandType.Quit);

// ...

async Task CreateProject(TaikunCliCommand command)
{
    string projectName;
    string kubesprayVersion;

    if(command.HasProjectName)
    {
        projectName = command.ProjectName;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please specify project name");
        projectName = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // basically the same for the kubespray version
    // ...

    await Project.Create(projectName, kubesprayVersion);
}
```

Or even better: Separate the logic whether the input shall be requested from requesting the input

```cs
TaikunProjectInfo CreateProjectInfoFromCliCommand(TaikunCliCommand command, 
                                                  Func<string> requestProjectName, 
                                                  Func<string> requestKubeVersion)
{
    string projectName;
    string kubesprayVersion;

    if(command.HasProjectName)
    {
        projectName = command.ProjectName;
    }
    else
    {
        projectName = requestProjectName();
    }

    // similar for the kubespray version

    return new TaikunProjectInfo(projectName, kubesprayVersion);
}
```

You can call this like

```
var projectInfo = CreateProjectInfoFromCliCommand(command, RequestProjectName, RequestKubesprayVersion);
await Project.Create(projectInfo.Name, projectInfo.KubesprayVersion);
// ...

string RequestProjectName()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please specify project name");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}

string RequestKubesprayVersion()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please specify project kubespray version");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```